# [Android Interface]What is it? can I create it by?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAqrE.png)

I want to create this tube but I don't know (Methord , class , view or other) to create it.

Can you answer to me by link , method, other .

thank you for every answer

Answer (score 6):

That is a `ProgressBar` widget, with `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`. The top one uses the platform-standard imagery for Android 1.x/2.x. The bottom two replace the background with their own `LevelListDrawable` that replaces the yellow with green.